# How to differentiate between Permission Declined and User Dismissed the permission dialog?

Tags: android, permissions, notifications

I am implementing the Notification permission on Android 13+,
Before showing the system dialog, I am showing an alert dialog that explains why the app needs this permission, with options **Let's Go** and **Later Maybe**

Everything is fine in most normal flows, like:

> 1. User taps **Let's Go**, System Permission Dialog is shown, User taps **Allow**, that's it.
> 2. User taps **Let's Go**, System Permission Dialog is shown, User taps **Don't Allow**, Dialog dismissed (both)

The following one is a problematic flow:

> User taps **Let's Go**, System Permission Dialog is shown, User taps
> **Don't Allow**, Dialog dismissed (both), after a couple of days, the user is shown the alert dialog again, taps **Let's Go**, and then Declines the permission. It happens a couple of times until the System's Permission dialog is exhausted.
> NOW when I request in a nice way, would you like to allow permission for notification, the user taps **Let's Go** but this time, the System Notification does not appear. Creating a confusing user experience.

There is no option to see in advance that the System's Permission Dialog won't appear at all, so one could refrain from starting that flow.

There is only `PERMISSION_GRANTED`, and `PERMISSION_DENIED` if I check using the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`. There should be a third state `PERMISSION_DENIED_PERMANENTLY` or something to check in advance.

The weird thing is if user just dismisses the dialog, callback retuns `PERMISSION_DENIED` same as tapped **Don't Allow** but this won't exhaust the System's Permission Dialog. I DECLIEND the permission twice and thrid time System's Permission Dialog did not show up, but I dismissed the dialog more than 30 times and it still continued showing up.

I hope I made this scenario clear, let me know if you found any workaround for it.

Thank you